# How to send an email on a private telekom smtp?

Tags: python, email, smtp

I want send an email automatically, but i get this error message:
"Connection unexpectedly closed: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer"

I tried a few smtp server methode, but it can't work.

My code is here:

```
fromaddr = "test@gmail.com"
toaddr = "test2@gmail.com"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "test"
body = "Test"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain')) 
#server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.example.com', 25)
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('mail.dt-one.com', 443)
#server.connect("mail.t-online.hu",2525)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login('myuser','mypassword')
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Are you sure about the port? For SMTP using SSL I would expect 465 or 587, certainly not 443

Comment: Im not sure about this 443. I check it with 465 and 587.

Comment: I get "connection timed out" whit 465 and 587 too.

Comment: `Connection timed out` != `Connection unexpectedly closed`. Anyway, we can't help much here because we have no details about the mail server in question. Please get the details about the correct port and what technology to use (e.g. SMTP, SMTP over TLS or SMTP over SSL).